# how to sum the columns of a 2 dimensional array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, sum

ok, I'm trying to add the the sum of the columns of a two dimensional array but so far i was able to add the total of the sum of the rows but Not the other 3 columns. can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong?

[image: here is picture of my output]

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    File election = new File("voting_2008.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(election);

    String[] states = new String[51];
    int[][]votes = new int[51][3];


    for (int s=0; s < 51; s++)
    {
        states[s] = sc.nextLine();
    }

    for(int c=0; c < 3; c++)
    {
        for(int s=0; s < 51; s++)
        {
            votes[s][c] = sc.nextInt();

        }

    }
    Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
    fmt.format("%20s%12s%12s%12s%21s", "State", "Obama", "McCain", "Other", "Total by state");
    System.out.println(fmt);
    int TotalSum; 
    TotalSum = 0;
    for (int s=0; s < 51; s++)
    {
       fmt = new Formatter();
       fmt.format("%20s", states[s]);
       System.out.print(fmt);
       for(int c=0; c < 3; c++)
       {
           fmt = new Formatter();
           fmt.format("%12d", votes[s][c]);
           System.out.print(fmt);

       }


           int sum =0;
           for (int col=0; col < votes[s].length; col++)
           {
              sum = sum + votes[s][col];

           }

           TotalSum += sum;
           fmt = new Formatter();
            fmt.format("%21d", sum);
            System.out.print(fmt); 



       System.out.println();

    }
    Formatter fmt2 = new Formatter();
    fmt2.format("%20s%12s%12s%12s%21s", "Total", "", "", "", TotalSum);
    System.out.print( fmt2 );
}
```

}

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & textual data rather than code snippets & a screenshot of your IDE!

Comment: It looks like you are asking us to write code to finish your homework question.  "Sorry: no can do!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of simple changes to fix your issue:

1> Merge the first two for loops as:

```
    for (int s=0; s < 2; s++){
        states[s] = sc.next();
        for(int c=0; c < 3; c++) {
            votes[s][c] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

1. Define a new colSum[] next to TotalSum as below:

   ```
   int TotalSum = 0;
   int colSum[] = new int[]{0,0,0};
   ```
2. Update vote printing for loop to do the column sum as well:

   ```
      for(int c=0; c < 3; c++) {
          colSum[c]+=votes[s][c]; // <-- new line to do the column sum
          fmt = new Formatter();
          fmt.format("%12d", votes[s][c]);
          System.out.print(fmt);
      }
   ```
3. Print the columns sum in last line as :

   ```
       fmt2.format("%20s%12s%12s%12s%21s", "Total", colSum[0], colSum[1], colSum[2], TotalSum);
       System.out.print( fmt2 );
   ```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You're logic is a bit off.

After your first for loop:

```
for (int s=0; s < 51; s++)
{
    states[s] = sc.nextLine();
}
```

you have already consumed the first 50 lines in the file and each element in the "states" array holds the text of each line.  The next time you try to read from the scanner, you're on the 51st line, so as you would only be reading the grand total at the bottom of the file, as you originally stated.

What I think you're wanting to do is for each state (each line in the file) sum together the numeric columns 1, 2, and 3?

Here's some sample code that should help:

```
File election = new File("voting_2008.txt");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(election);

String[] states = new String[50]; // 50 united states
int[] votes = new int[50];

// only grab the first 50 lines, each line a different state
// assuming file layout is: stateName,count1,count2,count3
for ( int i = 0; i < 51; i++ ) {

    states[i] = scanner.next();

    // grab the next 3 numbers
    int voteTotal = 0;
    for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
        voteTotal += scanner.nextInt(); 
    }
    votes[i] = voteTotal; // total votes for this state

}

// ... display results ..
```